# Can Azure OpenAI Service Preview deal with confidential info?

Tags: azure, azure-openai

We would like to use Azure OpenAI Service Preview for work efficiency.

But the [DPA](https://wwlpdocumentsearch.blob.core.windows.net/prodv2/MicrosoftProductandServicesDPA(WW)(English)(Jan2023)(CR).docx?sv=2020-08-04&se=2123-04-29T00:36:23Z&sr=b&sp=r&sig=KgvUjWQVCyTPPfHrE6fwBhL0P6bm%2BC4YQEu2LN74TFo%3D) says customers should not use Previews to process Personal Data or other data that is subject to legal or regulatory compliance requirements.

Should we not handle confidential info?

(We already understand this sevice is technically secure and we can actually believe it is able to process our important data. But DPA seem to forbidden such usecase...)

I would like to know the followings:

1. Whether Azure OpenAI Service can be used for dealing with confidential data in buisiness use cases or not.
2. How should we interpret the description of DPA.

Answer (score 0):

Azure OpenAI doesn't use customer data to retrain models. For more information, see the Azure OpenAI [data, privacy, and security guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/legal/cognitive-services/openai/data-privacy?context=%2Fazure%2Fcognitive-services%2Fopenai%2Fcontext%2Fcontext).